# Search By Partial word of a sentence in elastic search

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I am very new to Elastic Search , I want to search a result based on a partial word of a sentence , like the search string is

> "val"

and it should search the result with string value

> "value is grater than 100"

but if I am using a query

```
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchProject>()
searchDescriptor.Query(q =>
                    q.Wildcard(m => m.OnField(p => p.PNumber).Value(string.Format("*{0}*", searchString)))

                );
```

it will work only for one word string like

> "ValueIsGraterThan100"

if I use something like this

```
var searchDescriptor = new SearchDescriptor<ElasticsearchProject>()
searchDescriptor.Query(q =>

                    q.QueryString(m => m.OnFields(p => p.PName).Query(searchString))

                );
```

This will work for entire word , like i have to provide search string as

> "value"

to search

> "value is grater than 100"

only providing `val` will not work.So how i can fulfill my requirement ?

Comment: please provide your mapping and field name, where you searching against

Comment: yo can take it as , there is a table name `permit` and i am searching against a filed name `PermitDescription`. So permit description is here the field.

Comment: as is? i need a mappings, because that's crucial how your index is configured. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html

Comment: there was no mapping for this filed , I have added one like `.Properties(props => props
                    .String(s => s
                        .Name(p => p.PermitDescription)
                        .Index(FieldIndexOption.NotAnalyzed)
                        .IncludeInAll(false)
                    )`
is it something you want.

Comment: @Mysterion is there any thing i am missing , as i am not working from the start , so have very less knowledge about the configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Your field currently is not_analyzed, You can use [edge n-gram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) analyzer  made up of edge ngram filter to token your field before saving the fields on inverted index. You can use the following settings

```
PUT index_name1323
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "autocomplete_analyzer": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "standard",
                        "lowercase",
                        "filter_edgengram"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "filter_edgengram": {
                    "type": "edgeNGram",
                    "min_gram": 2,
                    "max_gram": 15
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "test_type": {
            "properties": {
                "props": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "analyzer": "autocomplete_analyzer"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can simply use both query_string or term filter to match both your documents to val

```
POST index_name1323/_search
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "default_field": "props",
            "query": "val"
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I  added a mapping in `PutMappingDescriptor` with `FieldIndexOption.Analyzed`, and created a wild card filter query. It worked for me. By the way thanks for your answer.

Comment: yes wildcard on analyzed field will also work without using edge-n gram tokenizer, i just prefered this analyzer for you for performance as wildcards on query are pure string mining high IO operations. Thanks